# Not able to generate XML from php

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I need to hit a url by either means and after the response I just want to generate an xml showing done.

Here is the code that is trying to generate the XML and before this all the JS is placed:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                <?php echo "var link = '".$url."';"; ?>
        loadXMLDoc(link);

        function loadXMLDoc(link)
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",link,true);
        xmlhttp.send();         
        }
    </script>


$data = "";
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$data="<parameters>";
    $data .= "<result>Product Added To The Cart</result>";
$data .= "</parameters>";

echo $data;
```

Here is the output I am getting

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 5 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Here is the source of the output I am getting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var link = 'http://obaoja.com/checkout/cart/add/product/7027/qty/1/'; loadXMLDoc(link);

    function loadXMLDoc(link)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",link,true);
    xmlhttp.send();         
    }
</script>
<parameters><result>Product Added To The Cart</result></parameters>
```

**I just need `<parameters><result>Product Added To The Cart</result></parameters>` in XML** format.

Comment: that doesn't look like output at all, that looks like your javascript function and two custom elements.

Comment: This is the source of the output

Comment: What's the use of having those XML elements when you're assigning it to an HTML elements body? It will most likely just render as plain text. Also, post the code generating the actual XML. This sample has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: The code that is generating the xml is provided and before that it is only Javascript and Div tag.

Comment: This code is confused and confusing. Either you're generating Javascript into an AJAX response (huh?), or you're generating what should be the AJAX response into the page making the call.

Comment: Anyway, clearly the output you're getting is wrong, so figure out why there's **both** the script **and** the XML data, and make it so there's only one as appropriate. Since you only included the code doing the latter, we can't tell why something else is being run.

Comment: The thing I need is XML and need to hit a url before it.

Comment: @HarsimranSingh You can't include a script in an AJAX response and expect it to get executed. (Not in a straightforward way that is.) AJAX responses are **data**, not webpages that the browser processes as usual. Why not just have the code that does the AJAX call hit that URL before it processes the data?

Comment: Sorry @millimoose but can you give some example. as i don't know other method

Comment: @HarsimranSingh An example of what? I don't know what you're trying to ultimately accomplish with this. If I understand you correctly, somewhere else in your code you have some other piece of Javascript that tries to get the data in `<parameters>...</parameters>`. Just include the code you're sending along with the data right now in the success callback of that other AJAX call.

Comment: @HarsimranSingh Or I understood you wrong, in which case you'll have to make your question clearer. Include all code relevant to what you're trying to do - i.e. make an ajax call, then hit an URL when it succeeds?

Comment: @millimoose Question updated as what the code is and what is the output and what I need out of it

Comment: @HarsimranSingh Okay, so to start from scratch: **why** are you outputting both Javascript and XML data? (Whatever you're trying to do this is the wrong way to do it.) If you just need the XML data, then don't write out the `<script>`. And where are you *reading* this XML data in the end? (Also: why include jQuery then not use jQuery's AJAX features?)